# JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript

I keep finding some JavaScript that looks like the example below.  Can someone explain this as I have not seen JavaScript written like this before.

What is "SomethingHere" and the colon represent?  I'm used to seeing function myFunction() but not what is shown below.

```
 SomethingHere: function () {

              There is code here that I understand.
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the other answers here indicate, it is an example of object literal notation. An object can be declared like so:

```
var myObj = new Object();
```

However, it can also be declared with object literal notation, like so:

```
var myObj = { };
```

When using object literal syntax, one can immediately add methods and properties inside the open and closing braces using the syntax *name* : *value*. For example:

```
var myObj = {
    name: 'Dave',
    id: 42,
    SomethingHere: function() {
        /* function body */
    }
};
alert(myObj.name); // Displays Dave
alert(myObj.id);   // Displays 42
myObj.SomethingHere(); // Executes method SomethingHere
```

"SomethingHere," in this case is a "method," meaning that it is a function that is a member of an object. It's significance lies in the special variable **this**. In the following two function definitions, **this** refers to the browser window variable (assuming that are running the code in a browser):

```
function foo() {
    /* this.document refers to window.document */
    /* this.location refers to window.location*/
}

var bar = function() {
    /* Same as above, just a different syntax for declaring the function.
    /* this.document refers to window.document */
    /* this.location refers to window.location*/
}
```

In this example, however, **this** refers to the enclosing object, myObj:

```
var myObj = {
    name = 'Dave',
    id = 42,

    myMethod: function() {
        /* this.name refers to the name property of myObj, i.e., 'Dave' */
        /* this.id refers to the id property of myObj, i.e., 42 */
        /* this.location is undefined */
        /* this.document is undefined */
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

It's object literal notation. It's a way of declaring objects using the following form:

```
{
    propertyName: value
}
```

So for example:

```
var obj = {
    fruit: "apple",
    id: 123,
    sayHello: function() { return "Hi"; }
};
alert(obj.fruit);
alert(obj.id);
alert(obj.sayHello());
```

Comment: more precisely: object *literal* notation.

Comment: ...also your `alert(obj.sayHello())` is incorrect as sayHello uses alert() itself.

Comment: Sure enough. Don't hesitate to edit the post on occurences like this.

Comment: OK -- I tend to avoid editing other people's answers, as it almost always seems heavy-handed to me.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the people. Well, if you ever come accross one of my posts again, edit away :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically in that scope/syntax, you have to have named arguments and this is the way to get the function into the object.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object in Javascript like this:

```
var obj = {
 a: 1,
 b: 2
};
```

You can also have attributes which are functions:

```
var obj = {
 SomethingHere: function() { alert("hello"); },
 b: 2
};
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: No reference to JSON, as it can be misunderstood with the data format.

That's JavaScript object notation. You can make a function like:

```
var SomethingHere = function() {

};
```

or...

```
var Singleton = {
   SomethingHere: function()
   {
    ...
   }
}
```

Comment: That is technically *not* JSON. It is just a JavaScript object. JSON is a data format based on JavaScript objects but its syntax is a bit more strict. For example, key names must be enclosed in quotes. See more here: http://json.org/

Comment: It isn't JSON. JSON is a data format based on JavaScript's syntax for object literals, array literals and various other basic data types. It does not include functions.

Comment: JSON happens to be an acronym of "JavaScript Object Notation". Only meant that.

Comment: The term "object notation" doesn't appear to appear anywhere in [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

Comment: @Joel - none the less, JSON is a very specific thing - as it it has a *specification*. Check out the link (json.org)

Comment: Bottom line is that "SomethingHere" is a variable which is defined to be a function. You can use "=" to define a function outside of a JavaScript object or by using ':" to make it a property of an object.

Comment: @Chris, as defined in JSON.org: "JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format."

Comment: @Joel: If you're going to take things from the spec, then keep going to the part where it talks about key names enclosed in strings. Your sample code is not **JSON** as used in parlance, as described in the specification; you edited your answer to remove the mistaken phrase so I retract my down vote. Thanks for correcting your answer!

Comment: @Chris, thank you! I did my reading, and naturally, you're right, it isn't technically JSON.

Comment: If you want to reach for even more accuracy, you could mention that it is object literal notation, as opposed to using constructor/instance/prototype objects: http://www.davidpirek.com/blog.aspx?n=JavaScript-Class-Constructor-vs.-Object-Literal:-Difference-in-Implementation-and-Inheritance  Enjoy the reading :)